# problema al grabar audio con mediarecorder en JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio

quiero hacer que al darle a un botón html comience a grabar audio y al darle al mismo botón, pare la grabación, se guarde en base64 (texto) y se reproduzca lo grabado (para guardarlo en base de datos y al hacer una petición recuperar el base64 y convertirlo de nuevo en archivo de audio y que se escuche).
Ahora estoy en el primer paso, en el cual graba audio y se guarda en base64 PERO solo lo hace bien al grabar un segundo audio, el primero nunca me lo guarda bien...

```
let isRecording = false;

let audioChunks = [];

var mediaRecorder;
var chunks = [];

function enviararchivoaudio(){
console.log("enviararchivoaudio funcion")

if (isRecording) {

        console.log("deteniendo stream audio");
            var botongrabaraudio2 = document.getElementById("perm_camera_mic"); 
            botongrabaraudio2.innerHTML = "perm_camera_mic";
            botongrabaraudio2.classList.remove('transparent');

     mediaRecorder.stop();

 var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
 chunks = [];

var audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log("audioURL es: "+audioURL)

 audio = new Audio(audioURL);
  audio.play();

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
var base64data = reader.result;
console.log(base64data);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    isRecording = false;
} //fin del if

else {

        var botongrabaraudio = document.getElementById("perm_camera_mic"); 
        //formato con el texto que envio
      // record_voice_over
         botongrabaraudio.innerHTML = "record_voice_over";
         botongrabaraudio.classList.add('transparent');

    

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function(stream) {
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.start();

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
  chunks.push(event.data);
 };
 });

    isRecording = true;
 }

}//fin funcion
```

El caso es que cuando grabo un primer audio me salta el error:

**GET blob:https://miweb.com/3be57d79-10c3-41e8-8a6a-9e35e28b375d net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE
botones.js:267 data:
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.**

y cuando grabo el segundo audio, se reproduce **EL PRIMERO...**

Comment: Suena a que no estás esperando a que se genere el primer audio: es un proceso que puede tardar unos segundos y hasta que la función que declaras para onloadend no se ejecute no deberías intentar reproducirlo

Comment: y como puedo hacer esa pequeña espera, para que se genere el audio y lo pueda convertir en base64 correctamente? Aparte de eso lo que veo es que cada vez que grabo va aumentando el audio añadiendo el ultimo audio y escuchandose al grabar el siguiente...

Comment: Puedes añadir el HTML? Si le das a [edit] y pulsas Ctrl + M podrás añadir todo tu JS, HTML y CSS para crear un [mcve] que nos ayudaría a encontrar y solucionar el problema